# How to find Azure Function App IP for white-listing

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have developed a PowerShell script to send mail to specified users using MX record DNS once in a day. Mails are delivered successfully but all mails are going in to Junk folder.

Exchange team have analyzed the message header and responded that sender IP addresses needs to be white-listed.

How to find Azure Function IP or IP range as I am using Consumption plan for my Function App.

Regards,
K Senthilrajan

Comment: "Unfortunately we can't identify the IP address ranges for your function more specifically than the datacenter IP addresses." [IP Address white-listing for Azure Function running under Consumption Plan](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/464)

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately things have changed since Kim's answer. You now have to go into a JSON file via Azure Resource Manager to find the possible outbound IP addresses. Per the [current Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses#dedicated-ip-addresses):

> 1. Sign in to the [Azure Resource Explorer.](https://resources.azure.com/)
> 2. Select **subscriptions** > **{your subscription}** > **providers** > **Microsoft.Web** > **sites**.
> 3. In the JSON panel, find the site with an id property that ends in the name of your function app.
> 4. See *outboundIpAddresses* and *possibleOutboundIpAddresses*.

Alternatively, you can also do it via the Az Powershell Module:

> az webapp show --resource-group <group_name> --name <app_name> --query outboundIpAddresses --output tsv
>
> az webapp show --resource-group <group_name> --name <app_name> --query
> possibleOutboundIpAddresses --output tsv

Comment: I don't seem to have "providers", only "resource providers", and they're not clickable, so the "az" command works fine, for those who have the same issue

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot because I couldn't find this info anywhere else.

Answer (score 9):

In the background behind an Azure Function is an Azure App Service. So, how do you find the IP addresses it use?

There is the section containing ***current*** outbound IP addresses in the App Service settings page, see

[image: Azure App Service - Outbound IP Addresses]

But keep in mind, since the platform is a PaaS service, it might, without any notice, move to other hardware and get a totally different set of outbound IP addresses.

See [this](https://twitter.com/jussipalo/status/985781858020610049) twitter conversation with Azure Support, for more details. Conclusion of the discussion is the IP range is not static and may change.

The only surefire way to know what IP's an Azure Function may be using, is to refer to the XML document published by Microsoft Azure that contain the [entire IP range of all data centers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653), making this task a little difficult to implement.

Comment: Is it possible to get IP range if we user App Service Plan?

Comment: One, very expensive option is to deploy your functions on an isolated App Service plan and through it get a dedicated IP, but that costs quite much. Other than that, the IP ranges for the individual data centers are found in the XML document you can download from the link in my post above. I'm not aware of any way to more explicitly tell exactly what subset of IPs App Services (maybe?) use.

Comment: Thanks Kim, what about SMTPauth is ir possible to achieve the same using SMTPauth

Comment: Note that the XML document published by Microsoft Azure has been superceded with this one https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519 which is updated weekly

Answer (score 0):

I used this technique to dynamically identify the IP

Periodically the health endpoint will be called and the returned IP will be whitelisted.

```
app.get("/health", function(req, res) {
    unirest
    .get('https://<fn-appname>.azurewebsites.net/ipinfo')
    .headers({'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    .send()
    .then((response) => {
        res.send(response.body);
      });

});

app.get("/ipinfo", function(req, res) {
    const ipaddress=req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
    res.send({ip_address:ipaddress});
});
```